# wget gets Read error (Connection reset by peer) in headers

Tags: wget

I searched a lot but no solution helped me with this problem where I get this error constantly.

> HTTP request sent, awaiting response... Read error (Connection reset
>   by peer) in headers. Retrying.

I tried the following inputs.

```
wget url
wget -O url
wget -O url username="user" password="pass" host="host" (something like this)
```

I am just trying to download html from a secure website page but all the time it shows the error. So I tried to download any web page but still not working. Is it any server configuration problem?

Comment: Can you ping the destination?

Comment: Try cURL, there may be restrictions based on user-agent

Comment: Usually user-agent filtering gives an error.  Connection reset by peer is usually network issues.

Comment: Thank You. let me try.
@Tripp, yes I can ping.

Comment: I tried curl. but it shows same error. @sotona

Comment: @GLYusuf but you can load this url with your desktop browser, right?

Answer (score 4):

This error can occur if you access a website via **HTTP** but it's trying to redirect you to **HTTPS**

So if your command was

```
wget http://url
```

Try changing it to

```
wget https://url
```

Answer (score 3):

I encountered a similar issue today, our IT team suggests to use "https" over "http" in the url and use "wget --no-check-certificate", it worked for me.

Websites may stop serving the unencrypted http transfer at some point, which might lead to the issue.

Answer (score 0):

try with "sudo" privilege, it worked for me.

```
sudo wget url
```

Answer (score -1):

This following command works form me.

> wget -O test.html http://url --auth-no-challenge --force-directories